# Python nested list comprehension to count occurrences of same string across lists

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I need to transform the following list:

```
[
  [u'starred', u'review'],
  [u'starred', u'review'],
  [u'starred', u'review', u'pinned'],
  [u'starred'],
  [u'starred'],
  [u'starred', u'review']
]
```

into the following dict

```
{
  u'starred': 6,
  u'review': 4,
  u'pinned': 1
}
```

I've got the feeling that it should be possible by using list comprehension or a generator expression, but I'm not sure though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
import itertools, collections
c = collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*your_list))
```

Comment: This is perfect. Will wait for other answers before accepting.

Comment: Instead of `chain(*your_list)` you could use `chain.from_iterable(your_list)` but that's just a minor point. Good answer!

Comment: Wow, after less than 2 minutes already 5 upvotes? That's quick.

Comment: @MSeifert turns out `chain.from_iterable(your_list)` is slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Flatten you list with generator expression and use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(x for sub in L for x in sub)
```

Comment: Two reasons for accepting this answer: First and foremost it is faster. In a quick benchmark I get 1.08 sec for this one vs 1.42 with the `itertools.chain` one.
Second: while it is not that important and the `itertools` answer ends up being cleaner (easier to understand at a short glympse), this is still the answer which shows how to actually use nested list comprehension / generator expressions.

Comment: @DanielF What's your benchmark? For `[map(unicode, range(1000)) for _ in range(1000)]`, the `itertools` one is faster for me (about 2.71 seconds vs 2.99 seconds (for ten executions)).

Comment: I'm for-range(1000)-looping a result of a database fetch. If you want to I can put the database result into a json file and post it to pastebin. Also, I'm leaving the Counter call out. `list(itertools.chain(*your_list))` vs `[x for sub in your_list for x in sub]`. I will doublecheck later today not to leave the burden on you. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Looks like you're right, when not leaving the Counter call out, using `itertools.chain` is slightly faster.

Comment: @DanielF With those two expressions, my test times drop to about 0.27 seconds for itertools and 0.33 seconds for the generator expression. So the latter is still slower for me. And both are *much* faster than when building a `Counter`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann How odd, you're right. I need to get my act together... Don't know what happened there.

Comment: Ultimately, when passing the `itertools.chain` result to the Counter, then this is faster than passing the list of the list comprehension to the Counter. But generating the list is faster, that was my mistake. So thank you a lot for verifying.

Comment: @DanielF Like I said, for me the itertools way is faster with and without Counter. Maybe it's different for you because of how you fetch the data. Especially since `itertools.chain` fetches all sublists before chaining them. If that's a disadvantage somehow, that would explain why it's slower and why `chain.from_iterable` is faster (as you reported under the other answer), as it doesn't do that.